# Console Application Code Error

Tags: c#

In my code,

```
            int x;
            int y;
            x = 7;



            if (x == y)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The numbers are the same!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The numbers are different.");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


            for (int i = 0; i < y; i--)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} sheep!", i);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


            string[] colors = new string[y];
            colors[0] = "green";
            colors[1] = "yellow";
            colors[y] = "red";


            Console.WriteLine("Your new code is {0}.", Code(x, y));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }   

            static int Code(int myX, int myY)
            {
                int answer = myX * myX - myY;
            }
    }
}
```

there is an error that states:

> 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.Code(int, int)': not all code paths
>   return a value'.

I am not sure what is wrong with the code. Solutions?

Comment: no value returned in function code

Comment: Your code is not complete, there is a part missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty straight forward. Your function:

```
static int Code(int myX, int myY)
{
    int answer = myX * myX - myY;
}
```

Requires that you return an integer. I think you meant to do this:

```
static int Code(int myX, int myY)
{
    return myX * myX - myY;
}
```

Comment: @tmw No problem. Don't forget to upvote answers you find helpful and to accept the answer that you find best resolves your question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the value of 'answer', as otherwise, as the error stated, the code does not return a value.

Note: Whenever you use an 'int' or 'string' in the way that you were using it, you **must** always return a value

```
static int Code(int myX, int myY)
    {
        int answer = myX * myX - myY;
        return answer;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static int Code(int myX, int myY)
{
     int answer = myX * myX - myY;
}
```

Your function doesn't return a result (just as the error states). It should be:

```
static int Code(int myX, int myY)
{
    int answer = myX * myX - myY;
    return answer;
}
```